# PyDev change background colour of tooltips

Tags: python, eclipse, editor, ubuntu-12.04, pydev

I'm using PyDev in Eclipse (on Ubuntu 12.04).  The default background colour for the tooltips is black.  Given some of the text in the tooltips (links to function definitions) is dark blue, I can't read it.

I've looked under Preferences->Editors->Text Editors and Preferences->PyDev->Editor but can't find an appropriate setting.

How can I change this?

Thanks

**Edit:**

This turns out to be a Ubuntu specific bug - it exists in versions of Ubuntu at least to 12.04.  Workaround is linked in my answer below.

Comment: This is a application question not a programming question? Ask in the Eclipse Forum? http://www.eclipse.org/forums/

Comment: See the FAQ.  Questions about common programming tools are appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: you tought me something, so thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is caused by a bug in Eclipse:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eclipse/+bug/1047353

It's fixed, but not for Ubuntu 12.04.  There is a workaround here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/70599/how-to-change-tooltip-background-color-in-unity/70665#70665

Answer (score 1):

These setting are `default settings for my eclipse` in `windows` (which I use for android development)

I haven't faced any such issue that is mentioned by you,but yes i had faced those settings issue with `Appcelerator TITANIUM.`

And after applying my eclipses setting to that Titanium IDE, my problem was resolved

**For Editor**

[image]

```
**Line Number Foreground**      (R 120 G 120 B 120) (Hue 0 Sat 0 Lum 120)

**Current Line Highlighting**   (R 232 G 242 B 254) (Hue 213 Sat 22 Lum 254)

**Print Margin**                (R 176 G 180 B 185) (Hue 213 Sat 12 Lum 185)

**Find Scope**                  (R 185 G 176 B 180) (Hue 333 Sat 12 Lum 185)

**Selection Foreground Color**  (R 242 G 242 B 242) (Hue 0 Sat 0 Lum 242)

**Selection Background Color**  (R 202 G 202 B 202) (Hue 0 Sat 0 Lum 202)

**Background Color**            (R 242 G 242 B 242) (Hue 0 Sat 0 Lum 242)

**Foreground Color**            (R 202 G 202 B 202) (Hue 0 Sat 0 Lum 202)

**HyperLink**                   (R 202 G 202 B 202) (Hue 0 Sat 0 Lum 202)
```

**Annotations**

[image]

```
**Bookmarks**                          (R 34 G 164 B 99 ) (Hue 150 Sat 202 Lum 164)

**Break Points**                       (R 0 G 0 B 255) (Hue 240 Sat 255 Lum 255)

**Debug Call Stack**                   (R 219 G 235 B 204) (Hue 91 Sat 34 Lum 235)

**Debug Current Instruction Pointer**  (R 198 G 219 B 174) (Hue 88 Sat 52 Lum 219)

**Errors**                             (R 255 G 0 B 128) (Hue 330 Sat 255 Lum 255)

**Filer Search Results**               (R 237 G 237 B 252 ) (Hue 240 Sat 15 Lum 252)

**Info**                               (R 244 G 200 B 45) (Hue 47 Sat 208 Lum 244)

**Matching Tags**                      (R 212 G 212 B 212) (Hue 0 Sat 0 Lum 212)

**Occurences**                         (R 212 G 212 B 212) (Hue 0 Sat 0 Lum 212)

**Override Indicators**                (R 176 G 33 B 207) (Hue 180 Sat 207 Lum 205)

**Search Results**                     (R 206 G 204 B 247) (Hue 243 Sat 44 Lum 247)

**Spelling Errors**                    (R 255 G 128 B 64) (Hue 20 Sat 191 Lum 255)

**Tasks**                              (R 0 G 128 B 255) (Hue 210 Sat 255 Lum 255)

**Warnings**                           (R 244 G 200 B 45) (Hue 47 Sat 208 Lum 244)

**Write Occurrences**                  (R 240 G 216 B 168) (Hue 40 Sat 76 Lum 240)
```

**Linked Mode**

[image]

```
**Current Range**                      (R 50 G 70 B 120) (Hue 223 Sat 149 Lum 120)

**Range Linked To Current**            (R 180 G 215 B 255) (Hue 212 Sat 75 Lum 255)

**Editable Range**                     (R 170 G 185 B 220) (Hue 222 Sat 58 Lum 220)

**Final Caret Location**               (R 0 G 180 B 0) (Hue 120 Sat 255 Lum 180)
```

Quick Diff

[image]

```
**Changes**                   (R 204 G 163 B 205) (Hue 299 Sat 52 Lum 205)

**Additions**                 (R 188 G 188 B 222) (Hue 240 Sat 39 Lum 222)

**Deletion**                  (R 0 G 0 B 0) (Hue 0 Sat 0 Lum 0)
```